# Is it possible to to take screenshot and paste it using keyboard only?

Tags: shortcut-keys, screenshot, paste

I frequently create material containing screenshots from computer. For ~15 years using Windows and Word it was Alt+PrintScreen -> Ctrl+V and the image was in place.

In Ubuntu similar result can be achieved in dozens of different ways/programs but none has similar ease.

Is there a way to get screenshot of active window to say LibreOffice Writer using few keyboard commands only?

This is in Ubuntu 16.04 and 17.10.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yes there is. Below I listed some shortcuts which are on Ubuntu 14.04 by default. Screenshots will be copied to clipboard automatically.

**Ctrl + Alt + PrintScreen** = Active window

**Ctrl + Shift + PrintScreen** = Selected area

**Ctrl + PrintScreen** = The whole screen

Comment: And can you Ctrl+V the image to Writer?

Comment: Yes you can. Give it a try.

Comment: Ctrl + Alt + PrintScreen -> Ctrl + V (in Gimp) says "There is no image data in the clipboard to paste." Ubuntu 16.04 and 17.10. Ctrl + Shift + Printscreen does work. And Ctrl + Printscreen. Not with Alt. ... Darn! Now it works! Mind Blown.

Comment: This works for the default Ubuntu 17.10 as well.

Comment: Works for 18.04.1 LTS, but Shift + PrintScreen also allows you to copy using a "Selected area", but does *not* copy it to the clipboard, but stores the screenshot file into ~/Pictures.  I am not sure that is by design or what. @jiipeezz perhaps you can update your answer to include Shift + PrintScreen too (but to include a note about it not being copied to the clipboard)?